# Page Unresponsive & Memory Leak Issue with Vuejs Application Running on Azure

Tags: azure, vue.js, memory-leaks, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a web application which is developed using VueJS and .Net Core Web Api and it is currently running on Azure. Whenever there is an error in production, no matter if it is with front-end or back-end, the site freezes with page unresponsive prompt. The error also causes memory leak as memory and cpu usage for the browser process increase significantly. The only way to continue after the error is to close the page and reload. This is not happening in development environment. In our localhost, it shows the error message and continue without being frozen. Any idea would be greatly appreciated. Many thank!

Comment: Memory leaks in Vue applications do not typically come from Vue itself, rather they can happen when incorporating other libraries into an application.

Answer (score 0):

We need to use some method to do some clean-up and solve the memory leak prior to removing the select DOM. We will keep a cleanup property in our Vue instance’s data object and we will use the [**Choices API’s**](https://github.com/jshjohnson/Choices)  `destroy()` method to perform the cleanup.

Eg: I am using clean function in my .js file

```
Clean: function () {
    // use the reference to Choices to perform clean up here
    // prior to removing the elements from the DOM

    this.< mention Method you want to cleanup>.destroy()
}
```

If you’re already using destroy in your project please follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69451689/15997690)

Refer [Avoiding Memory Leaks in Vue)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/avoiding-memory-leaks.html#Resolving-the-Memory-Leak)